# how to modify the each cell in the excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

[image]

I want to read data from input excel sheet and write it in a outut excel sheet in the format shown below.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:*(with the below code you can read Book1.xlsx, convert the excel file to `list of lists`, and write `list of lists` in excel file(Book2.xlsx))*

**EDIT**: I add `start_cloumn` and `start_row` as your request for set where start `row` and `column` for adding `0x`.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

df = pd.read_excel(r'Book1.xlsx')

lst = [df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
 
start_cloumn = 4 # added this line on EDIT
start_row = 2 # added this line on EDIT

with xlsxwriter.Workbook('Book2.xlsx') as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    for row_num, data in enumerate(lst):
        if row_num >= start_row:
            data = ["0x" + str(d) if column_num >= (start_cloumn-1) else str(d) for column_num, d in enumerate(data)]
        worksheet.write_row(row_num, 0, data)
```

output:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: tried to append "0x" at the begging and "," at end of each cell [worksheet.write_row(row_num, 0, "0x"+ data +",")] but is throwing the error. thank you

Comment: @anu, I edit the code block as your request and add this line `data = ["0x" + str(d) for d in data]` in `for-loop`, maybe helps you

Comment: thanks a lot. how to write col1..n and row1..n also in the output excel and if data starts at E5 or somewhere how do i find col1/row1 and then append "0x".

Comment: @anu, I edit the code block as your new request but I don't understand the second part of your question

Comment: ,data = ["0x" + str(d) if 'row' not in str(d) else str(d) for d in data] : if there is other strings than "row" 0x will be prefixed to that string, how to write row if there is different strings( like A2: CAT, A3:RAT,A4: DOG) . thank you

Comment: second part of my question is: lets consider first 6 columns and 5 row i have some string and i want to write it in output excel as it is , and data starts from cell G6 i want to append "0x". in such case how to use loop

Comment: @anu, I don't understand your question again, if you can edit your question and add pictures that I make sense of your question.

Comment: updated the question please have a look. thank you

Comment: @anu, The shape of the two input files is the same, is correct?

Comment: @anu, I edit code and add code for your new request, maybe this helps you.